# longitudinal data collected over time

Tags: time-series, panel-data

I have a data set of 183 subjects in whom I have recorded their oxygen saturations (in percentage units) every 10 second intervals for 60 minutes (360 time points).

I have a specific question:

I wish to create a nomogram for oxygen saturations in this population for this 60 minutes. Should this be handled as a "time series data" or a relational data (longitudinal data)?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the observations are collected from the same sample (183 people) over time (for every 10 sec up to 60 Min), this is a panel data. This is also balanced panel since all obs are reported the variables.
IF you wish to see group or age wise dynamics...you can use this data as panel. But,

When you look at one person's data over time, This can also be used as 183 Time series. you can analyse the individual dynamics here.